# Custom content type and custom list view

Tags: theming, nodes

Hi totally new to Drupal and I've managed to set everything up I needed to. Custom content types, taxonomies etc.

Firstly I'd like to know how to link to a page which will display all the posts in my custom content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to build "lists" of things then I would check out the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). You will create a new content view and filter by the new content type. If you're struggling building a View just google for 'drupal views tutorials' and there will be a ton to show you how to build things with views.